# Can you create custom shortcuts like @+id and @string in Android

Tags: android

There are a number of shortcuts available in the android designer like the bold portion of the following strings:

android:id="**@+id**/txtUserName"

android:text="**@string**/UserName"

What are these called? Is it possible to create a custom one like this?

android:text="**@customString**/UserName"

Comment: These are predefined resource directories/names that you cannot change. The AssetManager and assets directory in your project might be interesting...

Answer (score 0):

Those are for defining resource id..

> - The at sign (@) is required when you're referring to any resource    object from XML. It is followed by the resource type (id in this
>     case), a slash, then the resource name.
> - The plus sign (+) before the resource type is needed only when you're    defining a resource ID for the first time. When you compile
>     the app,    the SDK tools use the ID name to create a new resource ID
>     in your    project's gen/R.java file that refers to the 
>     element. Once    the resource ID is declared once this way, other
>     references to the ID    do not need the plus sign. Using the plus sign
>     is necessary only when    specifying a new resource ID and not needed
>     for concrete resources    such as strings or layouts.

For more info refer [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#TextInput) and also [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)